# How to access a variable in DataContext from XAML (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid

For example, i have an array in CodeBehind, that i want to bind to a DataGridComboBox in XAML.

First, i know i have to put the array in the DataContext(ok), but then how i access the array from XAML?

And how i make reference in the DataGridComboBox to bind the items from the array into the ComboBox?

My problem is working with DataContext, i can't really understand how to work with the DataContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, the DataContext is simply the object that provides the root path for Binding Expressions in the XAML.

So when you set DataContext, perhaps in the code-behind like:

```
string[] DataArray = new[] { "John", "Peter", "Paul" };`
this.DataContext = DataArray;
```

You can access it from the XAML like:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Count}" />`

You are now accessing the Count property on DataArray, by virtue of the DataContext property.

If you wanted a particular array element, you could specify an index:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=[0]}" />`

If you wanted to use the array as the source to an element that supports a collection:

`<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" />`

No arguments to a binding expression simply accesses DataContext directly, in this case, an array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok i have picked up your examples and tried them, and it beginning to make sense to me. But now, imagine if isn't an array, but a DataTable. Imagine that i have loaded a DataTable with only a column from a table in a Database, and i want to put all values of that column as items in ComboBox, how i make reference in ComboBox to get all the values in the cells?

Comment: How about: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Columns["ColumnName"]} />

Comment: No, i can't get the contens from the column, it will show in the comboBox this "System.Data.Row". I think the solution is passing the values from DataTable to array of Strings and then passing it to the DataContext. Ok this works well with a ComboBox, but doesn't work with a DataGridComboBox.

Comment: Try: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Columns["ColumnName"]["ColumnName"] /> Also, if you feel I've answered your original question, please accept my answer. Thanks.